# Why is there a speed difference when slicing a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am slicing a large amount of dataframes over time.

However, the run times of the two codes below show a big difference.

code1.

```
for i in city_list:
     from_line = df[(df['Timestamp']==time_from) 
                               & (df['city']==i)]
     to_line = df[(df['Timestamp']==time_to) 
                               & (df['city']==i)]

     value1 = len(from_line['Value'])
     value2 = len(to_line['Value'])
     ...
     ...
```

code2.

```
for i in city_list:

     from_line_sub = df[df['Timestamp']==time_from]
     from_line = from_line_sub[from_line_sub['city']==i]

     to_line_sub = df[df['Timestamp']==time_to)]                           
     to_line = to_line_sub[to_line_sub['city']==i]

     value1 = len(from_line['Value'])
     value2 = len(to_line['Value'])
     ...
     ...
```

Code1 takes over an hour, while code2 takes just over 20 minutes.

I think the result of slicing is the same, but what is the reason for this speed difference?

This speed difference can be seen not only with `==` condition, but also with `>` and `<` conditions.

Maybe I am missing something?

Thanks for reading this far.

Comment: You can increase the speed if you vectorize your process. Use `groupby` and `agg` for example. Please post a sample of your data.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is because the line

```
from_line = df[(df['Timestamp']==time_from) & (df['city']==i)]
```

is not short-circuiting on the `&` operator, like you'd expect. That means it's evaluating both conditions for every row in `df` to return the rows where both conditions are `True`.

In the second example, this line

```
from_line_sub = df[df['Timestamp']==time_from]
```

is returning a smaller subset of the original dataframe (presumably much smaller, given the execution time difference), then the second condition is only applied to that subset of results in the next line.

---

Here's an example that shows short-circuiting does not work as expected.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': pd.Series([1, 2, 3], dtype=object),
                   'B': pd.Series([4, 5, 0], dtype=object)})

a1 = df[(df['A'] == 1) & (1 / df['B'] == 0.25)]
print(a1)
```

If the `&` operator were short-circuiting the second condition, you'd expect the `1 / df['B']` to be evaluated only for the first row (where `df['A'] == 1`), and only that row would be printed. This code throws a `ZeroDivisionError: division by zero` error though, so the second condition must be evaluated for all rows.

Comment: I think there is no short-circuiting to be expected, right? The bitwise `&` is requiring all elements on both side of the operator while `and` can achieve short-circuiting as it is working on single elements.

Comment: @mozway I think most people do expect short-circuiting behavior in boolean operators, but even if you don't, the reduced number of evaluations is still the reason for the speed-up.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried filtering in another order?

How long does code2 take with this modification?

```
for i in city_list:
 
 df_t = df[df['city']==i]  # filter only one time by each city

 from_line = df_t[df_t['Timestamp']==time_from]
                       
 to_line = df_t[df_t['Timestamp']==time_to]

 value1 = len(from_line['Value'])
 value2 = len(to_line['Value'])
 ...
```